# Class 'CodeIgniter\Entity\Entity' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create a simple entity class. I follwed the docs exactly, made a file called Biz.php and stored it in the `app\Entities` folder.

Then, I tried this piece of code

```
<?php
namespace App\Entities;

use CodeIgniter\Entity\Entity;
class Biz extends Entity{

}
```

But it gives the error: `Class 'CodeIgniter\Entity\Entity' not found`.

However, if I change it from `use CodeIgniter\Entity\Entity;` to `use CodeIgniter\Entity;` it works fine.

I copied the original error source code from the [CI4 docs](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/models/entities.html#create-the-entity-class)

[image]

Is this a bug on my end? Codeigniter's source code o it was just a typo in the docs?

*If so, should I make a new pull request to get it fixed*

Comment: What is your version of CI?. In the change logs Codeigniter/entity/entity was introduced in CI 4.1.2 where the Codeigniter/entity class was deprecated. [CI 4.1.2 Changelog](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/changelogs/v4.1.2.html).

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Oh, that was the problem